# If/Elif Python Statement

Tags: python

New to this. My autochecker says that line 3 is incorrect.

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")
s = float(score)
if s >= 0.9
    ("A")
elif s >= 0.8
    print ("B")
elif s >=0.7
    print ("C")
elif s >=0.6
    print ("D")
elif s < 0.5
    print ("F")
else
    print ("Enter number")
```

Comment: You're missing the colon (`:`) after each `if/elif/else` line

Comment: Also `("A")` doesn't do anything without the word `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need a colon after each if/elif/else line.
2. You need to add print before "A".